# Create an alias url in NGINX (using proxy_pass inside Docker)

Tags: python, docker, nginx

All I need is add a link named **mydomain.com/demo** that points to a certain page **mydomain/story/80**

the problem is that I have two NGINX configuration levels:

1. the NGINX on the host with which I handle multiple domains, each of which is redirected via proxy_pass and a Docker container;
2. the NGINX configuration of the container itself.

Where should I add the change?

This is my configuration:

**1) HOST NGINX**

```
server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        sendfile on;

        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ...

        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:7001;
        }
}
```

**2 CONTAINER NGINX AND RELATIVE DOCKER-COMPOSE**

```
upstream rest-api {
        server backend:80;
        }

server {

        sendfile on;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ...    

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

        location ~ ^/api/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

                proxy_pass http://rest-api;
        }

}
```

```
  mydomain:
    image: foo/mydomain
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "7001:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - webnet
```

Comment: Try `rewrite ^/demo$ /story/80 last;` at host nginx configuration. Instead of `location ~ ^/api/ { ... }` you'd better use `location /api/ { ... }` (same but slightly less resource consuming).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried and gives me error 404

Comment: Is `mydomain.com/story/80` accessible at all? `Try `rewrite ^/demo$ /story/80 break;` inside the `location` block at host config.

Comment: If `index.html` is a client-side app and `/story/80` is a route interpreted by `index.html`, you cannot point `/demo` to `/story/80` in Nginx unless you use a redirection. E.g. `location = /demo { return 301 /story/80; }`